# Visual Studio 2010 Crashes When Opening A XAML File

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, crash

My Visual Studio 2010 installation has begun to refuse to open XAML files. As soon I try to open a XAML file, VS crashes with the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working" error message.

The error details are as follow:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.40219.1
  Application Timestamp:    4d5f2a73
  Fault Module Name:    agcore.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.0.60531.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4de47967
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000fe4b4
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 1c2e
  Additional Information 2: 1c2e894c07ffbfa788cce4871fe5d2a7
  Additional Information 3: 4324
  Additional Information 4: 4324091cc08bb1d80e5272e04862e058

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I have tried loads of different things to fix this, uninstalling and reinstalling Silverlight and the developer tools, uninstalling the whole of Visual Studio and the Silverlight tools and even trying to stop the XAML designer from opening and simply opening just the XAML code.
The whole re-install of Visual Studio seemed to fix the problem for a couple of hourse, but now it is straight back to crashing as soon as I open the XAML file.
Is there anything else that I can try?

Thanks for any help,

Martyn.

Comment: could you upload the file to a location on the internet and post the link here so that we could take a look at it ?

Comment: It happens whenever I try to open up any XAML file, regardless of whether they are files I have created or are sample files from tutorials.

Comment: alfonso, my solution was to fully reinstall Windows and Visual Studio etc. This fixed the problem and it hasn't happened again since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open the XAML file the following way:

Right click on the XAML file, select the open with --> XML(Text) Editor -- set it to default, and click ok, the xaml file opens.

They say this happens because you don't have the right version of Silverlight developer run-time installed on your machine, but i never happened to find the right one for my machine what ever i  do it kept crashing so i learnt to live with it now, the above workaround is good.